# Set username/password in rtsp url

Tags: rtsp

I am retrieving video from an IP-Camera using rtsp using a java web application;
The rtsp url has embedded username/password in the url itself which seems to be quite insecure. e.g. rtsp://user:password@ip/...

Is there a way to to prevent sending the username/password in the URL.

What will be the best possible way to secure the URL?

Comment: the best way is not to send username and password in the URL

Comment: how will you send it then ? What way other than performing a Basic Authentication ?

Comment: just send url, user will enter user/pass

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 6):

Given a username and password, you can set them using environment variables like this:

```
USER=myusername
PASSWD=mypassword
```

For example, if your camera's IP address is 192.168.0.101, then you can access the camera via its RTSP URL:

```
rtsp://"${USER}":"${PASSWD}"@192.168.0.101:554
```

Comment: Please add some details to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Thank you! Worked! Example: rtsp://admin:mypassword@192.168.0.26:554/onvif1

Answer (score 4):

Username/password in the URL is a way to **write** url. Rtsp agent will use it to authenticate with basic or digest authentication. So your password will be encoded and transported as a rtsp header.